# Mongoose query hangs after callback

Tags: javascript, mongoose

This must be user error, but I have reduced the example as far as I can, and I just can't spot it.

Here I make a simple query, which calls the callback with a result and no error. However, the program just hangs afterwards; it never exits.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

const M = mongoose.model("someSchema", someSchema);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost", err => {
    console.error("connection error", err);
    M.find({}, (queryError, result) => console.log("result:", result, "error:", queryError));
});
```

Result:

```
connection error undefined
result: [ { _id: 55ffada74fb9958d13ec7c4b, name: 'asdf', __v: 0 } ] error: null
```

(program hangs instead of exiting)

I'm sure I've overlooked something really basic, but I can't spot it in the guide, and juggling things around isn't helping. What is really weird, is that I have a bunch of more complex Mongoose models that are working elsewhere.

- Mongoose: ^4.0.5
- babel-node: 5.8.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will stay open until you close the MongoDB connection (however, this does not mean it "hangs"). Simply put a `mongoose.disconnect();` when you're finished and the script will quit.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost", err => {
    console.error("connection error", err); // TODO better handle error
    M.find({}, (queryError, result) => {
        console.log("result:", result, "error:", queryError);
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
});
```